# Birthday only Month and Day

Tags: contacts

We only have month/day data for most people. How can I change the format for the constituent profiles to just do month/day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we just have the month/day for the birthdate we set the year to a generic year like 1900. You still are able to get your birthdate notifications and run all the reports you want. It's just that the calculation of the contact's age will be wrong. We use a year that would make the person VERY old so that we know that the year is not known. It has worked for us without any issues.

Comment: Thank you! How do you setup the birthday reminders?

Comment: We have a report that is run daily.  Once civiRules is working we will use it to send emails automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to store the month and day and not the year of the Birth Date?

In that case you actually do not want to store the Birth Date. That is not a change in format, that is a different kind of information.

My suggestion is to create 2 custom fields for it: an integer field for the month and a second integer field for the day.

Comment: If I do this, how do I setup getting notifications of upcoming birthdays?

Comment: Which CMS are you using? Drupal, WordPress or Joomla? And which method are  you using now for birthday notifications?

Comment: We are using Joomla platform. And haven't setup a birthday reminder thing yet but that was going to be my next step for research.